# Is there a way to avoid losing my progress when Uplay is down?

Tags: might-and-magic-heroes-6, ubisoft-connect

Last night, I tried to play Heroes VI, only to find that Uplay was down. I was offered an "offline" mode, but upon running the game in "offline" mode, I found that none of my previous saves were available - I'd have to start from the very beginning, the tutorial campaign, all over again.

Needless to say, I'd rather *not* have my save games exist only at the whims of Ubisoft's DRM. Is there any way I can store my save games locally so that they're available in offline mode?

Comment: In Fallout3 you could log in to Microsoft Live, load a save, log off and continue playing (and hence saving) in off-line mode. Not sure if that works with UPlay though. If I know Ubisoft right, you can't, but it's worth giving a shot. I should have known better than to by a f****ing Ubisoft game. I don't want this UPlay thing and I don't want to register on yet another site to be able to play my games. When they complicate things for us legit users, I may as well get a pirated copy to save myself the hassle. I just bought Assasin's Creed 2 and came here to find a workaround for Uplay. In any c

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope, sorry. I've run into this myself and you can't get the saved games from the Ubisoft servers, you will have to start anew with the campaign in offline mode to not depend on their servers which right now may be lacking stability.

They are very well known for this DRM, see Assassins Creed 2, which unfortunately didn't offer an offline mode like HOMM 6.

Comment: Well that bites.

Comment: I moved to a place without internet connectivity. Does that mean that I lose ALL my saves until I reconnect to the conflux?

Comment: @Jonn there do seem to be some locally stored files, but I'd have to investigate where offline mode saves games to to see if they could be futzed into compliance.

Comment: Do share when you do. I'll be tinkering around myself. I'd hate to lose all those hours of campaign just so I could pick up where I left of.

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution to get my games back, just put Uplay in offline mode by clicking the gear/setting button.